# Can't install Ubuntu 13.10 due to insufficient available disk space

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted

When trying to install Ubuntu, on the preparing to install page, the first bubble is left unchecked. The one where it says, "has at least 5.9 GB available drive space". Everything else is checked, "is plugged into a power source" "is connected to the internet". I can't figure out how to successfully delete any space on the disk.

That's because there isn't anything on this machine. I had windows 8 but got rid of it for Ubuntu. I tried Ubuntu but then it kept freezing so i tried re-installing it again, and it went crazy again. And now, after my third try, it shows this.

On GParted, under partition, it shows unallocated with a size of 883.03mib. I've tried other methods of deletion here but they all fail by using the terminal.

Comment: How did you "get rid" of Win8? GParted may show the whole drive as "unallocated" not because it actually is but because of a partitioning error, or what GParted perceives as an error (whereas i.e. Win or drakdisk don't): http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#disk-unallocated. You may need to repartition the drive again using GParted.

Answer (score 0):

The 5.9 GB are about drive space **not** allocated to any partition.

If you have nothing on the drive to keep, delete all partitions (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, and all the others). In gparted you might have to first unmount them.

The other option is wiping everything out using fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
o
w
q
sudo reboot
```

Comment: when i type that first command, "sudo fdisk /dev/sda". it says, "fdisk: unable to read /dev/sda: Invalid Argument."

Comment: i should also note that i'm doing this via live-cd since my laptop won't let me access anything at this point without it.